# How do I prevent windows from detecting a USB GPS as a mouse?

Tags: windows, usb

When most NMEA-compliant GPS devices are connected to a windows machine via USB they appear as a COM port. Sometimes Windows (I've seen this on XP and Vista) detects that new serial device as a mouse and the cursor goes crazy.

How do I tell Windows to stop detecting the GPS device as a mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions - see [here](http://www.euronav.co.uk/eurohelp/techdocs/TN036.htm) and [here](http://www.mp3car.com/vbulletin/mp3car-infill-g4-double-din-car-computer/130287-real-solution-g4-gps-being-detected-windows-crazy-serial-mouse.html).

Let us know what works for you!